# String and pointer in C++

Tags: c++

Below is the code for which I want to know the answer to 2 questions in the side comment. Please help me

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *p="Hello";
    cout <<*p;     //gives H
    cout <<*(p++); //also gives H.Why?
    cout <<*(p++); //gives e.
    cout <<*(p++); //gives l.
    cout <<*(p++); //gives l.
    cout <<*(p++); //gives o.
    cout <<*(p++); //gives no output.Why? It should give some garbage value!
}
```

Comment: Make that `const char *`, not `char *`.

Comment: @chris : That's a different issue.I want to understand the strange output for current code.

Comment: p++ means post increment , first value is taken , then incremented

Comment: Look up the postfix increment operator. `x++` returns the old value of `x` and increments it. Also look up null termination.

Comment: To all those who gave answer to the second part using the cocept `hello\0`.Let me ask If I add another line `cout <<*(p);` i still get no output ,instead of some garbage.Is it related to undefined behaviour?

Comment: If you increment beyond the `\0`, then you will get whatever happens to be in memory there. It is likely to look like garbage. If it happens to be a `0`, then you will see nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What p++ does is increment p and return the old value of p, so *(p++) will always return the character stored at *p and after the statement *p will point to the next character.

```
cout <<*(p++); //gives 0.
```

This does not actually give `0`, it gives the character "o", the last character in `Hello`.

```
cout <<*(p++); //gives no output.Why? It should give some garbage value!
```

This outputs the NUL character `'\0'` that terminates the string. It's a non-printable character, and where you're seeing this output you don't see any probably because the software decides to not print non-printables. If you look at the hex dump of the output for example you could see the NUL right after the o:

```
00000000  48 48 65 6c 6c 6f 00                              |HHello.|
```

If you added yet another `cout <<*(p++)` you *might* see garbage output, or the program might crash, or something else might happen, because it would be "undefined behavior."

Comment: :Thanks for your support Sir.How can I see the hex dump?I am using linux with g++.

Comment: Pipe the program's output to `hd` or to `hexdump -C` like this: `programname | hexdump -C`

Comment: What do those `00000000` at the beginning denote?

Comment: It's the seek offset, a 0-based position of the data in the file. Position 0 is the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

`*(p++)` gives `'h'` because you first ask the value and than increment the position of your pointer and it the same thing in the last line.

Comment: But won't the `p++` executed first as its inside the bracket

Comment: Postfix op returns original value. Prefix returns incremented

Comment: no the incremtation is done after the value of the point  is give to operation

Comment: The value of the expression `p++` is the value of `p` before the increment. Doesn't matter how many parentheses are involved.

Comment: More explicitly, `(p++)` returns a copy of the value of `p` and that copy is dereferenced by `*`; at any time after the copy is made, the `++` can take affect of `p` - that could be before or after the dereferencing because `()` doesn't create a "sequence point", but it doesn't matter when `p` is incremented because it's **copy** of the pre-increment value of `p` that will be dereferenced.  It may help understanding to consider a typical user-defined post-increment implementation: `T& operator++(int) { T copy(*this); ++*this; return copy; }`.

Answer (score 4):

1. If you use `p++` anywhere in your code, say:

   ```
   <some code> p++ <some code>
   ```

   It's equivalent to

   ```
   <some code> p <some code>;
   p = p + 1;
   ```

   In contrast, if you write:

   ```
   <some code> ++p <some code>
   ```

   It's equivalent to

   ```
   p = p + 1;
   <some code> p <some code>
   ```

   That should answer your first question.
2. The C-style strings automatically end with a \0 character. So if you declare:

   ```
   char *p="Hello";
   ```

   The compiler automatically adds a \0 to the end of that string for you (otherwise functions like printf would not know, when the string finishes). So your string is actually:

   ```
   "Hello\0"
   ```

   If you try to push the pointer further though, you will end up in invalid memory and you might encounter anything (garbage, which may be a series of zeros as well)

Comment: No undefined behavior here. The sixth character of "Hello" is `'\0'`, every time, guaranteed.

Comment: I downvoted, because you're wrong. The sixth character of "Hello" is `'\0'`. Nothing undefined at all.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I was mislead by OP's `cout <<*(p++); //gives 0` (instead of `//gives o`). Indeed, he is still in the valid memory. My mistake. Edited the answer.

Comment: +1 for a good overall explanation, but you don't address - of `cout << '\0'` - "gives no output.Why? It should give some garbage value!".  Actually, what the terminal chooses to do when fed a NUL is not defined by the C++ Standard, so it could have been garbage, clearing the screen, nothing etc..

Answer (score 3):

Doing `p++` actually requests the value, and then increment it. If you'd like to increment it then get the value incremented, use `++p`.

For your last question, the last value of a C string is always `'\0'`. That print nothing on the terminal in most case, but this is undefined behavior by the C++ Standard.

Comment: "'\0'. That print nothing on the terminal." - we're told that's the case here for Insane Coder, but the behaviour's not defined by the C++ Standard and it printing nothing is not something that should be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

The first `*(p++)` gives "H" because the ++ operator is defined to give its current value first, then do the increment.  The final `*(p++)` returns the character `'\0'`, because the string literal `"Hello"` points to an array of SIX characters, the last of which is `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when using the post-increment (such as your `p++`), the value is evaluated **before** the increment is done.

So in your code, your first `cout << *(p++);` will print 'H' because it will evaluate the value of `p` **before** the assignment, which is the address of `p`, and then the value of `p` is incremented.

To increment the value of `p` before it is evaluated, use pre-incremental `++p`.

So this is what would happen in your code:

```
int main()
{
    char *p="Hello";
    cout <<*p;     //gives H
    cout <<*(++p); //this time it will give e
    cout <<*(++p); //gives l.
    cout <<*(++p); //gives l.
    cout <<*(++p); //gives o.
    cout <<*(++p); //gives no output since the character after a string is always \0 (credit to answer below)
}
```

Hope this helps! =D

Comment: It shouldn't give garbage. It gives `'\0'` because all string literals end with `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
{
    char *p="Hello";
    cout <<*p;     //gives H.
    cout <<*(++p); //gives e.
    cout <<*(++p); //gives l.
    cout <<*(++p); //gives l.
    cout <<*(++p); //gives o.
    cout <<*(++p); //gives 0.
    cout <<*(++p); //will either be a garbage value or throw an exception
}
```

The ++p will increment the pointer, and then return the value. p++ pushes the value on the stack, increments the pointer, and pops the stack to return it. It might also use a register; the implementation details are kind of up to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *p="Hello";
cout <<*p;     //gives H
cout <<*(p++); //also gives H.Why?
```

Because post increment will increment `p` AFTER evaluation. 
To increment `p` BEFORE evaluation, use `*(++p)`

```
cout <<*(p++); //gives e.
cout <<*(p++); //gives l.
cout <<*(p++); //gives l.
cout <<*(p++); //gives 0.
cout <<*(p++); //gives no output.Why? It should give some garbage value!
```

There's a padding `\0` in every C-style strings.